# How to deal with responsive design and iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, responsive-design

Im struggling with a responsive design.

Everything is sized in percentage, and is beginning to work aprox as intended on "regular" screens.

Via javascript I determine window width and height, which sets the background image.
The background image is using the css3 "cover" property.

BUT everything apparently is messing up, on iPad/iPhone. 
When the pagecontent overflows the pageheight (which most of the pages do, and are supposed to) then the "cover" property apparently expands and shows the image way too big.
And height and margin-top are suddenly set way too high.

My guess is that iPhone/iPad is considering the entire content including the overflown content as the full page height, and not just the actual visible screen.... But I dont know how to deal with it.

Also, when I alert out the window width, I get: 980 on iPad, iPhone4, and iPhone3. which I guess suggests that I cant use window width, on iPhone/iPad....?

How do I deal with the mobile setup?

My hope was that I wouldnt need to create iPhone/iPad specific setups... but I am beginning to fear that I need to?

Here is the playgroundwith the design: http://basix.popweb.dk

Any help or advice?

Thx
JOhn

Comment: Have you looked at CSS and [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)?

Comment: Have you looked at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/?

Comment: yes, I am aware of the media queries. But I am trying to figure out how to deal with the issue, in the easiest way possible. To learn.

Comment: I checked out bootstrap. Which looks cool and promising, but perhaps a little too "done" for me to use right now. I would like to learn how this works, so for now, I will try to learn by doing. And thats what I would love some advice and help with. But thanks! Bootstrap looks way cool.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just checked your website on an iPhone and it seems to load ok, however the layout doesn't seem to responsive to me.

Anyway, are you using any CMS?

Also, as I learning material, I advise you to check http://themble.com/bones/
Even though it's a wordpress theme, the stylesheets are very well exmplained on what works what. Nevertheless it uses SASS or LessCSS (CSS preprocessors) which I advise to learn because it will save you a lot of time when writing CSS. It isn't hard at all, I've learned LessCss in about 2 hours http://lesscss.org/.